# setting only a few values as domain to enum in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, enums, phpmyadmin

How to set enum values in phpmyadmin..I want to set values '0' **or** '1' in phpmyadmin for my field using an 'enum' type ..

Comment: declare the data type of the column as enum and set its values.

Comment: ya f course i know how to declare the data type as enum..i just wnt to set its choices out of 0 and 1 only how do i do that..

Comment: hey thanx i got it.. was my bad..

Comment: It's not a good idea to use numbers as ENUM values, because they will be interpreted as indexes.

Comment: See the subsection **Handling of Enumeration Literals** in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html

Comment: If you want 0 and 1, why aren't you using the `BIT` type (which is shorthand for `TINYINT(1)`)?

Answer (score 8):

or under your phpmyadmin

- choose enum
- in `Length/Values` column put there  : `'0' ,'1'`

and your done

Answer (score 5):

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `old_column_name` `new_column_name` ENUM('0','1') DEFAULT NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

It's quite long time for this answer maybe no use for the one who ask this question, but might be useful for those who are new to phpmyadmin. To set a default value for Enum I have the following example.
**Type** = ENUM, **Length/Values** just put the value inside single quote like 'Male', 'Female' then **Default** choose *As defined:* in the box below just type Male without quote. Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE tableName
(
  enumColumn ENUM('0','1')
);
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d1f6/1)
- [MySQL ENUM Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html)

Answer (score 2):

Put Length/Values as it is for 0 and 1 '0' ,'1'

Answer (score 0):

use GUI of phpmyadmin => by selecting the ENUM in type and then just set the values.